# Trigger to run only after checkbox goes rom unchecked to checked

Tags: triggers, salesforce, apex

I want to run a trigger on Contact if a checkbox on Contact object goes from unchecked state to checked state and then do some processing on the records. I have this trigger on after insert and after update. The code works fine for update but if I check the box while creating a new contact record, the trigger does not detect the below condition in the code and therefore sends an empty list to contactTriggerHandler class.

if (Trigger.oldMap.get(con.Id).checkbox==false  && con.checkbox== true)

```
  trigger Contact on Contact (after update, after insert) {

List<Contact> listofContacts = new List<Contact>();
List<Contact> usersToCreate= new List<Contact>();
if (Trigger.isAfter) {

    if(trigger.isInsert){
           System.debug('After insert');
           
           if(RecursiveTriggerHandler.isFirstTime){
                RecursiveTriggerHandler.isFirstTime = false;
           for (Contact con : Trigger.new) {    
     
              Contact contacttoUpdate = con.clone(true,true);
              contacttoupdate.Nickname__c=contacttoUpdate.firstname;
              listofContacts.add(contacttoUpdate);  
                      
           }

           
                  
           System.debug(listofContacts);
           ContactTriggerHandler.AfterInsert(listofContacts);
           update listofContacts;
          }
       
      }


    else if(trigger.isUpdate){
       
           System.debug('After insert and update function');
           if(RecursiveTriggerHandler.isFirstTime){
                RecursiveTriggerHandler.isFirstTime = false;
           for (Contact con : Trigger.new) {    
     
              Contact contacttoUpdate = con.clone(true,true);
              contacttoupdate.Nickname__c=contacttoUpdate.firstname;
              listofContacts.add(contacttoUpdate);  
              if (Trigger.oldMap.get(con.Id).checkbox==false  && con.checkbox== true) {  
             
                 usersToCreate.add(contacttoUpdate);
              }        
           }

           
           
          
           
           
           
           ContactTriggerHandler.AfterInsert(usersToCreate);
           update listofContacts;

          }
       
      }

   }

}
```

Here is the recursive handler class:

```
public class RecursiveTriggerHandler{
   public static Boolean isFirstTime = true;
}
```

Comment: (1) you should move all this logic into your handler class. Having logic in _both_ the trigger and the handler is an antipattern; (2) static Boolean recursion guards cause a wide variety of problems and you should check out [this SFSE post](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/296745/what-is-a-good-pattern-for-recursion-blocking-in-generic-trigger-handlers/296817#296817) for better patterns.

Comment: ok I will check that. One thing that I doubt is that in after insert case, it is not detecting the old value of checkbox as unchecked, because the record has not been created yet, hence making the condition false.  if (Trigger.oldMap.get(con.Id).checkbox==false && con.checkbox== true)  Is there any workaround for that?

Comment: Don't try to check oldMap in the insert case.

Comment: I tried adding separate condition for insert and update, updated the code above, no change. It still does not work on insert.